# Use different profiles with ZSH (in different terminal apps)

Tags: shell, terminal, osx, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I wish to use different ZSH profiles with different terminal apps on macOS. For example, use a profile with some prompt configuration A in iTerm, use a profile with a different set of aliases in Terminal.app, and use another profile with some startup scripts inside the integrated terminal in my IDE (VS Code, IntelliJ etc).

The terminal apps allow users to specify a "shells open with" command. For example, the default is `/bin/zsh` in my case. I have different '.zshrc' files setup with the correct configurations for different terminal apps. For example, 'vscode.zshrc', 'iterm.zshrc', 'intellij.zshrc' and 'bestconfigever.zshrc'.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can test if the respective programs set some environment variables. For example, iTerm sets `ITERM_PROFILE`

Comment: @muru could you elaborate on this? Is there a zsh command for testing terminal environments?

Comment: Say `[[ -z $ITERM_PROFILE ]] || source iterm.zshrc` and similarly for whichever variables the other programs set

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps -o comm= -p $PPID` (get the command name for the parent process) to see what program invoked zsh.

You can also check the `TERM` environment variable, but a lot of terminal emulators just set it to `xterm` because they're mostly compatible with xterm. What IDE-integrated terminals set `TERM` to depends on how featureful their terminal is. For example, Emacs uses `TERM=dumb` in `M-x shell` (simple command line where Emacs keeps control of the edition features) but `TERM=eterm-color` in `M-x term` (a full-fledged terminal emulator).

Some applications set environment variables, for example [as noted by muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420204/use-different-profiles-with-zsh-in-different-terminal-apps/420261#comment755377_420204) Iterm sets `ITERM_PROFILE`. Beware that if you launch a different terminal emulator from a shell, the shell in the second emulator inherits from the variables from the first one. Thus you may want to set `$ITERM_PROFILE` only after checking that the parent process is Iterm.

An alternative or complementary approach is to let the invoking program do the work. Zsh reads its configuration files from the directory `$ZDOTDIR`, falling back to your home directory if `ZDOTDIR` is unset. You can load e.g. `$HOME/.zshrc` from a `.zshrc` in a different directory, if you want to apply the default settings with a few modifications.